# Why the exception UsernameNotFoundException does not stop application?

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring Security to do authentication. Here is my code :

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/custom_login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String customLogin(){
        return VIEW_LOGIN_SUCCESS_NAME;
    }
```

Authentication

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {  

        com.startup.app.models.entities.User domainUser = userDao.getUserByLogin(username);  

        if (domainUser == null) {
            LOGGER.error("No user found with username: " + username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: " + username);
        }
      boolean enabled = true;  
      boolean accountNonExpired = true;  
      boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;  
      boolean accountNonLocked = true;  

      return  new User(  
              domainUser.getEmail(),   
              domainUser.getPassword(),   
              enabled,   
              accountNonExpired,   
              credentialsNonExpired,   
              accountNonLocked,  
              getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole())  
      ); 


    }
```

Here is the spring configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- configuration des urls -->
    <security:http auto-config="true">
    <!-- Define the default login page -->
    <security:form-login login-page="/custom_login" username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password" default-target-url="/loginSuccess"/>

    </security:http>


    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="authenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="authenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.startup.app.services.login.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl" /> 

</beans>
```

In the above configuration, i know i did not restrict access to page. I just first want to test the login process is working well.
I don't understand why the application does not stop when the UsernameNotFoundException is thrown. I don't have message in eclipse about except the logger i've used. Then the application continue to execute and display the login success page.
Someone could explain me please ?

Comment: Can you please add your configuration in springsecurity as well?

Comment: Do you have any spring security config to show?

Answer (score 1):

please change your login config:

```
<security:form-login 
     authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" 
     login-page="/custom_login" 
     username-parameter="email" 
     password-parameter="password" 
     default-target-url="/loginSuccess" 
     always-use-default-target="true" 
     authentication-failure-url="/custom_login" />
```

For even more control over the destination, you can use the authentication-success-handler-ref attribute as an alternative to default-target-url. The referenced bean should be an instance of AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

Comment: Could you give me the declaration of authenticationSuccessHandler ?

Comment: It's a class that implements org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler and you can implement loadUserByUsername() in this handler.

Comment: You mean i can implement onAuthenticationSuccess ?

Comment: Yes, you can use onAuthenticationSuccess but if you use BasicConfiguration , then you might not need handler. BTW, you still need to keep 'authentication-failure-url'.